# is there any way to use display:none with some delay (disappear over time)in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I made some element in script, and i styled them , my problem is how can i make some delay to this  :

```
var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
span.className = "close";
span.appendChild(txt);
li.appendChild(span);
var div = this.parentElement;
div.style.display= "none";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `setTimeout` for delay

```
setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display= "none"; }, 5000);
```

like

```
var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
span.className = "close";
span.appendChild(txt);
li.appendChild(span);
var div = this.parentElement;
setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display= "none"; }, 5000);
```

Comment: it works... but another thing i want this,is to disappear slowly .. with this function it disappear after 5 sec immediately .

Comment: @amirmasud111 I have added new codes in the snippet. please check.

Comment: @amirmasud111 you are most welcome